# SQL - delete rows where only one column changes

Tags: sql, select

I have a large table in SQL, in which an effective_from date column should update every time one of the other columns changes.  However, for some reason, there are numerous rows in which the effective_from date changes, but no other values have changed. For example:

```
CODE    NAME    EFFECTIVE_FROM
CCWA    Oak     1999
CCWA    Willow  2001
CCWA    Willow  2004
```

How can I delete the rows where the change in effective_from date doesn't provide any info.  e.g. the third row in the above table.

The tables are very large, so I would prefer to use SELECT statements rather than DELETE or ALTER which seem to be slow.

Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you are looking for:

```
SELECT Code, Name, MAX(EFFECTIVE_FROM)
FROM myTable 
GROUP BY  Code, Name
```

Comment: Thanks!  I think I was over-thinking things!

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
SELECT code, name, max(EFFECTIVE_FROM) 
FROM tablename
GROUP BY code, name
```

Answer (score 0):

Since it is the later date that adds no information, you want to select the **minimum** date value.

```
SELECT Code, Name, MIN(EFFECTIVE_FROM)
FROM CodeTable 
GROUP BY Code, Name
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to use `lag()`.  The result set without duplicates:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             lag(code) over (order by effective_from) as prev_code,
             lag(name) over (order by effective_from) as prev_name
      from t
     ) t
where (prev_code <> code or prev_code is null) and
      (prev_name <> name or prev_name is null);
```

This assumes that `code` and `name` are never `NULL`.  That is easy to incorporate in the logic (but it makes the `where` clause a bit complicated).

Answer (score 0):

Your question doesn not clearify the real result you want to achieve: if you want to permanently delete elements from the table, you need to use a DELETE, if your target is simply to filter out the duplicates you described, you can use a SELECT (and the elements will remain in the table).

The fact that you consider to use a DELETE make me suppose that this "duplicates" (except for the date) are not desirable.
In this case you can also consider to add a trigger that prevent the insertion when the informative fields (all fields except EFFECTIVE_FROM) aren't changed, in this way only interesting data changes will generate a new row.

Then you can execute a one-shot operation which delete all the duplicated elements that does not reflect any data change (operation to do by night, or however when the system has a low load or no one is using it, if the table is really very large as you typed).

This kind of solution changes the nature of this table, in fact you lose the historical information of updates without real data changes. Consider this solution only if these informations aren't necessary for your target.